# Perturbed Gram Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, perturbation-theory

Let $x_t  \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1}$, $\forall t\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $e_1$ be the first cannonical basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^d$, ie, $e_1 = (1,0,\cdots,0)$. Let us form a Gram Matrix
$$\sum_{t=1}^T(x_t + e_1)(x_t+e_1)^T $$

If I have a know a complete eigenspace decomposition of the above gram matrix, can I relate it to the unperturbed gram matrix
$$\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^T $$
More specifically if I know $U,\Lambda$ s.t
$$U\Lambda U^T = \sum_{t=1}^T(x_t + e_1)(x_t+e_1)^T$$
and if $\tilde{U}, \tilde{\Lambda}$ are s.t.
$$\tilde{U}\tilde{\Lambda}\tilde{U}^T = \sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^T$$. Is there any relation that $U \approx \tilde{U}$ and $\Lambda \approx \tilde{\Lambda}$?

EDIT: Okay, for example let us suppose $U=\tilde{U}$ that is the eigen vectors are same. And let us suppose $e_1$ is perpendicular to all but $u_1$ eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue. Then
$$\big(\sum_{t=1}^T(x_t + e_1)(x_t+e_1)^T\big)u_i = (\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tx_t^T)u_i + (\sum_{t=1}^Te_1e_1^T)u_i + (\sum_{t=1}^Te_1x_t^T)u_i + (\sum_{t=1}^Tx_te_1^T)u_i$$
$$\implies\lambda_i(V_T) = \lambda_i(\tilde{V}_T) + 0 + 0$$ for all $i\neq 1$
Is this correct?

EDIT: I think a more precise question would be : Upon a perturbation as shown above how do the Eigen vectors change

Comment: This might be irrelevant to the question, but why are you calling $\sum x_i x_i^T$ a Gram matrix? The definition I know of a Gram matrix is rather different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix

Comment: It's the same definition. The $\sum x_tx_t^T$ can be written as $X^TX$ where $X$ is a matrix with row vectors $x_t$

Comment: I don't follow: $X^TX$ is $\sum\limits_{i,j} x_i x_j^T$, not $\sum\limits_i x_i x_i^T$. (also I guess you mean column vectors, since if $x_i$ are row vectors then $x_i x_i^T$ is just a number, not a matrix)

Comment: I apologize, $\sum\limits_{i,j} x_i x_j^T$ is wrong, but $\sum x_i x_i^T$ is wrong as well: it contains only products of components of $x_i$ and $x_i$, while the Gram matrix has products for $x_i$ and $x_j$ as well.

Comment: To be utterly clear: let $a,b \in \mathbb R^2$, and consider their Gram matrix, which is $\begin{pmatrix} a^Ta & a^Tb \\ b^Ta & b^Tb\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a_1^2+a_2^2 & a_1b_1+a_2b_2 \\ a_1b_1+a_2b_2  & b_1^2+b_2^2\end{pmatrix}$. Now compare this to $aa^T+bb^T = \begin{pmatrix}a_1^2+b_1^2 & a_1 a_2 + b_1b_2 \\ a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2 & a_2^2 + b_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$ - they are **not** the same.

Comment: One suggestion I'd make is to replace $e_1$ with $te_1$. The advantage is that this lets you control the size of the perturbation and hopefully study the size of the effect. For instance, writing your initial matrix in this way as $M(t)$, you have $M(t)=M(0)+o(t)$.

Comment: It's notational. If you believe that a gram matrix can be written as $X^TX$ then it boils down to how you define the rows of $X$. In your example the columns of $X$ are the vectors $a$ and $b$. You can transpose the definition and get the second example

Comment: Ok, I get it now - your Gram matrix is not the Gram matrix of the set of vectors $x_t$, but of the set of vectors obtained by transposing the matrix $X$ (made up of columns $x_t$), which is highly non-evident from the wording to me.

Comment: Glad that got cleared up.

Comment: Sorry if my wordings were not clear

Comment: @Semiclassical. Maybe greshgorian could be used to show that eigenvalue s are at most a constant deviation?